# Firebase password signup doesn't save user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have used Firebase serval times by now and I am aware to how use it correctly.
I believe I have been stumble on a bug and would love to hear a solution in case you have one.

So - I used Firebase Google auth and it worked ok, then I decided to use the email + password method.
Now this is the weird part - I create a user, I get successful result but it doesn't save the user - cant see it in the Autherecation panel + cant sign in with the user after I sign out.

```
 mLoginContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mLoginProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful())
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mLoginContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mLoginProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable E-mail/Password on firebase console.

[Click here for Firebase Auth Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth#before_you_begin)

> How to enable E-mail/password sign-in:

```
In the Firebase console, open the Auth section.
On the Sign in method tab, enable the Email/password sign-in method and click Save.
```

hope it helps

Comment: I already used Firebase before as I mentioned, I already enabled it. - also if it wasnt enabled I would get error message not success.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this

Hope you have added `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'`in gradle dependencies

**Enabling Email/Password Authentication**

- Go to your firebase panel.
- On the left side menu you will see Auth, click on it.
  [image]
- Now click on Set Up Sign In Method.
  [image]
- Now click on Email/Password, enable it and press save.

**For SignUp**

*In your Registration activity*

//defining firebaseauth object

private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

onCreate

//initializing firebase auth object
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

//after the successful validation of username and password[call your registration method with following)

//creating a new user

```
 firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    //checking if success
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        //display some message here
                        Toast.makeText(this,"Successfully registered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        //display some message here
                        Toast.makeText(this,"Registration Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

- Click on Signup button in your design and if you got the success message. Check your firebase console.
  [image]

**For SignIn**

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(strUsrL,strPassL)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    if(task.isSuccessful()){

                                        Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }

                                }})
                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                                    Toast.makeText(this, e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Log.e("EXCEPTION",e.getLocalizedMessage().toString());
                                }
                            });
```

Comment: I am using the lastest dependencies 11.0.2 and already did everything you suggested. I get a success callback and still it doesnt show up in the panel    P.S. - thx for trying

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall application in emulator and try to provide an emulator with play store installation